# Programmatically install/uninstall apk from local asset directory to real device in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-install-apk

For Automation Testing I need to install on Apk programmatically and verify that the app is installed. and programmatically uninstall it and verify the app is uninstalled from the real device.
I am not looking for a UI to download and install, without any UI when I run the java file in the android studio it should install/uninstall.
Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this?

Comment: Is using ADB an acceptable solution?

Comment: You're looking for the `adb install` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can likely achieve this by using a combination of [PackageInstaller](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller) and [PackageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/pm/PackageManager)

As mentioned in the documentation for PackageInstaller, you'll need to be either the device owner or the affiliated profile owner, or it will require user intervention to complete installation.